# submit button value not sent on enter-key in IE7

Tags: php, html, form-submit

I've just noticed something that I'd never noticed before, while working on a (regular, no-JS) form.

If the form is submitted by clicking on the `Submit` button, it sends the `Submit` button data (`&submit=Submit` or some such).

However, the same form omits the `Submit` button data when submitted with the Enter key.

Example form:

```
<div id="messagebox">
    <?php 
        echo 'txt: [' . $_REQUEST['txt'] . ']<br>';
        echo 'submit_btn: [' . $_REQUEST['submit_btn']  . ']<br>';
     ?>
</div>
<hr>
<div id="formbox">
    <form method="POST" action="?">
        <input type="text" name="txt" id="txt" value=""><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit_btn" id="submit_btn" value="Submit"><br>
    </form>
</div>
```

[It should display both variables when a form is submitted, but it omits the Submit button data when Enter is pressed.]

I've been using the presence of the `submit` POST variable to do a server-side check. I guess I'm going to have to add a hidden input or something.

Anyway, the question: **Is this normal behaviour? If so, why?**

I'd assumed that the Enter key simply mimicked the Submit button. I'm now guessing it doesn't. If the Submit button is part of the form but just happened not to be clicked, why is it not sent with the rest of the data?

Comment: Can you please post the HTML code for it, because it depends on how you have the form labeled and set up? Thanks.

Comment: edited to add an example. you can see it in action here: http://www.altastic.com/formtest.php

Comment: Seems to work fine for me with the latest firefox, pressing enter.

Comment: I'm testing on IE7. IE problem, perhaps?

Comment: I'd normally test in other browsers, but I just discovered it now and I only have access to IE7 on this machine.

Comment: You could perhaps download a portable Chrome of Firefox, or I can let you teamviewer into a virtual server of mine.

Comment: Thanks, but I'll be able to check it in a few hours when I get on my other machine. I guess I'll just have to wait till then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With enter key the form submission happens correctly . But in IE7 , submit button value will be missing , strange behavior. So you can check whether form submitted or not , by using  a hidden text field with fixed text in that . Thanks

```
<div id="messagebox">
    <?php 
        echo 'txt: [' . $_POST['txt'] . ']<br>';
        echo 'submit_btn: [' . $_POST['submit_btn']  . ']<br>';
        echo 'checker: [' . $_POST['checker']  . ']<br>';
     ?>
</div>
<hr>
<div id="formbox">
    <form method="POST" action="form.php" name="frms">
        <input type="text" name="txt" id="txt" value=""><br>
        <input type="hidden" name="checker" value="POST SUCCESS">
        <input type="submit" name="submit_btn" id="submit_btn" value="Submit">  
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: You're right. It also seems to affect IE8. IE9 and all other browsers don't exhibit the behaviour, so I guess it is down to bloody IE's incompatibilities again.

Answer (score 2):

**You have missed underscore in the $_REQUEST,,Chck it out now**

```
<div id="messagebox">
    <?php 
        echo 'txt: [' . $_REQUEST['txt'] . ']<br>';
        echo 'submit_btn: [' . $_REQUEST['submit_btn']  . ']<br>';
     ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo I made while writing the example. The real example doesn't have that issue. If it did, nothing would get returned at all, no matter which method of form submission were used.